# Transpose Present Value of an Ordinary Annuity Formula for Interest Rate

Tags: finance

I'm having trouble transposing the formula for Present Value of an Ordinary Annuity in order to find the interest rate. The formula is:

[image]

Where

P=Present Value of an Ordinary Annuity

PMT=Payment

i=Interest Rate

n=Number of Terms

Not sure if it helps, but I managed to simplify the formula to this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists no closed-form expression for $i$ if $n>1$. Let $1+i=q$, your second equation becomes

$P=PMT\cdot \frac{q^n-1}{(q-1)\cdot q^n}$

Multiplying both sides by $(q-1)\cdot q^n$

$P\cdot (q-1)\cdot q^n=PMT\cdot (q^n-1)$

Multiplying out the brackets

$P\cdot q^{n+1}-P\cdot q^n=PMT\cdot q^n-PMT$

$P\cdot q^{n+1}-(P+PMT)\cdot q^n+PMT=0$

This is a polynomial with a degree of $n+1$. For $n=1$ it is a quadratic equation. It can be solved by using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). For $n=2$ the cardano formula can be maybe used. But for $n>2$ there exist no closed-form formula. In general you have to apply an approximation method, for instance the N[ewton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).